# How to use a ProgressBar on a basic themed Splash Screen?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'd like to replace ProgressDialog (which is deprecated) by ProgressBar in my Xamarin.Android application.

I have a Splash Screen which is a simple AppCompat Activity:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/favicon", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public partial class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
   ProgressDialog m_loginProgress;
}
```

With the following theme:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

OnCreate in the activity:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

   m_loginProgress = ProgressDialog.Show(this, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.connecting), Resources.GetString(Resource.String.please_wait), true);
   await SomeCallAsync().ContinueWith(() => m_loginProgress.Dismiss());
}
```

ProgressDialog was like "it just works". By that I mean:

1. The dialog is automatically centered on the screen
2. It has a title and a text.
3. User interactions are automatically disabled (not sure about that though)
4. Dismiss() would run on the UI thread automatically

Now I'm trying to use ProgressBar instead.

The code is a little trickier:

1. It seems that the underlying layout of the splash screen is of type ContentFrameLayout
2. I don't know how to center the ProgressBar because I can't have a Rule Added to a ContentFrameLayout.LayoutParams. I would need a RelativeLayout at a minimum.
3. I don't know how to add a simple text that is aligned with the progress bar

This is the code I have so far, and of course it does not work.

```
ContentFrameLayout layout = FindViewById<ContentFrameLayout>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
var p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
p1.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterInParent);
m_loginProgress = new ProgressBar(this, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleLarge);

m_loginProgress.Id = View.GenerateViewId();
m_loginProgress.LayoutParameters = p1;

layout.AddView(m_loginProgress);
var p2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);

tv.LayoutParameters = p2;
tv.Text = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.please_wait);

// Disable user interactions
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable, WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
// Show the progress bar
m_loginProgress.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

I'd like to know if I'm stuck and should create a content view for my splash screen.
If ProgressDialog works, ProgressBar should work too?

---

**EDIT**: OMG, I'm discovering that ProgressBar is not a dialog ! It is just the spinning circle. Everywhere I've red that ProgressDialog could be replaced by ProgressBar, but obviously this is more complicated than that.

The solution is to create a horizontal LinearLayout with the TextView and ProgressBar as children. Then add this linear layout as a child of the FrameLayout

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to below link to set progress bar and change progress bar color using colorAccent in color.xml :-

https://www.javatpoint.com/android-progressbar-example